# How to bind two properties in a class wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I would like to bind two properties in the viewmodel.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Format 
   {
     get { return format; }
     set
     {
        if (format != value)
        {
           format = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Format");   
        }
     }
   }

   public string FilterString
   {
     get { return filter; }
     set { filter = SomeFunction(value); }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
   }

}
```

So when the Format property changes It invokes FilterString set method.

What is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Set the FilterString property in the setter of the Format property?

Comment: I don't understand the problem - from the setter of `Format` you can call `FilterString = whatyouwant`. Just don't forget `OnPropertyChanged("FilterString")` then.

Comment: Ok I understand but Is that the correct way to bind properties in a class? or should events be used or other design pattern.

Comment: It seems like FilterString should be a read-only property that returns the value of SomeFunction. Does SomeFunction use the value of the Format property or how are the two properties related?

Comment: What kind of logic the properties have to do (have to implement in their setter) is independent of the property binding. I may be wrong, but maybe your question means if it is a good approach to do more stuff in the property setters, that may delay the processing (= the UI). You may do the actions async then...

Comment: How to do it async from inside the setter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WPF `multibinding` to bind a control to two fields, but in this case I think it makes more sense that the ViewModel would change FilterString when the Format is changed.

You'd use a `multibinding` when a control's value depends on two things because that's a GUI feature. In your case the ViewModel properties are logically linked, so it makes more sense for the code to be in the ViewModel.

To help you decide which pattern to use, ask yourself whether you'd want the same behaviour if you reused the ViewModel elsewhere.